# Speed up slow oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I have an Oracle query of the following format:

```
select col1, min(col2), max(col2) 
from table1
where col2 between add_months(to_date('12/06/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), -6) and to_date('12/05/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') 
and col3 = 'CLICKS' 
and col4 = '-8'  
and col1 in (select col1 from table2  where id = '05742') 
group by col1
```

In my schema, table1 is very large (millions, possibly billions of records), but table 2 is fairly small. Any ideas of how to optimize it?

Comment: What is the current query plan?  What indexes are available?  How selective are the various conditions?  How many of the rows in `table1` would need to be read in order to produce the aggregates?  How long does the query take?  How quickly do you need it to run?  Are materialized views an option?

Comment: any reason why you're using ADD+MONTHS on a date literal rather than changing the date's string?  Not a performance issue, just snagging.  Also, is `col4` really a string?  If not, why `'-8'`

Comment: What Justin says, plus.  How many rows (what percentage) fall in the date range specified?  How many of them have `col1` matching rows in `table2`?  Presumably you are not using partitioning (despite the potential billions of rows)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select t2.col1, min(col2), max(col2)
from table2 t2
join table1 t1 on t1.col1 = t2.col1
  on t1.col2 between add_months(to_date('12/06/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), -6) and to_date('12/05/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
  and t1.col3 = 'CLICKS'
  and t1.col4 = '-8'
where t1.id = '05742' 
group by t2.col1
```

This will be especially efficient when table2 is small and table1 is large.

Note: If the datatype of `table.id` is *numeric* (and not text), you should code the where clause condition as:

```
where t1.id = 5742
```

so the value type matches the column type, in case the db is stupid and casts the column to match the value instead of the other way around and therefore does not use this index, which I have seen happen many times.